# I want to know if the app features comply with Google Play guidelines

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We are considering introducing a chip function that can be traded between users in our app.
Chips can be used as actual currency at merchants of the app to purchase products and receive services.
We are considering making this chip available for purchase by credit card within the app.
I'd like to know if this feature can be released according to google-play guidelines. Where can I ask questions?

Comment: There are applications published on Google Play that contain such functionality. For example Locus Map and their LoCoins. So I believe this is compilant with Google Play rules.

Comment: IIRC , you will have to use google billing services for the in-app purchase to make it compliant